# How to save layers individually that can still interact with each other outside of Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, layer-style, blend-modes

What I am trying to do is to move a PNG of semi-transparent gradient above another PNG of a box in it within a video editor. So imagine the first gradient slowly moving to the left on top of the box, but the problem that I have run into is that once these layers are outside of Photoshop they don't seem to interact anymore.

I even tried layer the images in a browser and they don't have an effect on each other.

Do layers with blending modes overlay and soft light not interact once they are saved and outside of Photoshop? It also seems like my transparency from the gradient goes away completely, even though I saved it for web & devices and PNG-24.

I don't know if this is even possible, but I cant find any answers so I have to ask. Is there a  different file format that saves these properties?

Comment: It is quite doable to fake these effects with normal blend mode, some easier than others. It would help if you would show example images for this scenario, so that we can come up with an alternative method to achieve the same result, if possible.

Comment: Also, this might give you ideas: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10618/export-layers-with-bleding-options-and-shadow-to-png-format-using-photoshop/10642#10642

Comment: @Joonas I think for my particular case, which I will be using the images in a video editor, I can export the photoshop layers into after effects and the blending options will still work. I saw the other thread though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, blending modes have no effect outside of Photoshop. You can not save images with blending modes. It is simply not possible.

Comment: hmmm well thanks. Is there any alternatives or ideas to get similar results? I cant be the only person that has ever wondered about this.

Comment: save an image which has the exact appearance you want. If you overlay transparent images, they will simply sit on top of one another with no interaction.

Comment: I found another solution just in case someone stumbles upon this question in the future. Ultimately I needed the images to work in a video editor so I imported my Photoshop layers into After Effects. After that I can use the layers from photoshop in after effects and the blending modes still work the same way as in photoshop. But this answer is kind of tangent to the original question.